# Blender addons how to group custom created node trees?

Tags: python-3.x, blender

I'm trying to write blender addons that it can create custom nodes and we can operate them as normal blender builin nodes, especially for grouping them together, in my options it is a very import function, but now the code can add custom node, but grouping still does not work, so any tips?

```
#
# architect.py -- the blender addon
#

import bpy
import nodeitems_utils
from nodeitems_utils import NodeCategory, NodeItem, NodeItemCustom
from bpy.types import NodeTree, ShaderNodeTree, Node, NodeGroup, NodeCustomGroup, NodeSocket


bl_info = {
    "name": "Architect",
    "author": "Lei Liu",
    "category": "Node"}


class ArchitectEngine(bpy.types.RenderEngine):
    bl_idname = 'ARCHITECT_RENDER'
    bl_label = "Architect"
    bl_use_preview = False
    bl_use_shading_nodes = False
    bl_use_exclude_layers = False
    bl_use_save_buffers = False

    draw_callbacks = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None
        pass


    def __del__(self):
        pass


    # main scene render
    def update(self, data, scene):
        pass


    def render(self, scene):
        pass


class ArchitectNodeTree(ShaderNodeTree):
    bl_idname = 'ArchitectNodeTree'
    bl_label = 'Architect Node Tree'
    bl_icon = 'NODETREE'
    nodetypes = {}
    pass

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.scene.render.engine == 'ARCHITECT_RENDER'


class ArchitectNodeGroup(NodeCustomGroup):
    bl_idname = 'ArchitectNodeGroup'
    bl_label = 'Architect Node Group'
    node_tree = ArchitectNodeTree

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.scene.render.engine == 'ARCHITECT_RENDER'


# Custom socket type
class ArchitectSocket(NodeSocket):
    # Description string
    '''Architect node socket type'''
    # Optional identifier string. If not explicitly defined, the python class name is used.
    bl_idname = 'ArchitectSocketType'
    # Label for nice name display
    bl_label = 'Architect Node Socket'

    # Enum items list
    my_items = [
        ("DOWN", "Down", "Where your feet are"),
        ("UP", "Up", "Where your head should be"),
        ("LEFT", "Left", "Not right"),
        ("RIGHT", "Right", "Not left")
    ]

    myEnumProperty = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Direction", description="Just an example", items=my_items, default='UP')

    # Optional function for drawing the socket input value
    def draw(self, context, layout, node, text):
        if self.is_output or self.is_linked:
            layout.label(text)
        else:
            layout.prop(self, "myEnumProperty", text=text)

    # Socket color
    def draw_color(self, context, node):
        return (1.0, 0.4, 0.216, 0.5)


class ArchitectTreeNode:
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, ntree):
        return ntree.bl_idname == 'ArchitectNodeTree'


class DemoNode(Node, ArchitectTreeNode):
    bl_idname = 'DemoNodeType'
    bl_label = 'Demo Node'
    bl_icon = 'SOUND'
    typename = 'DemoNodeType'
    # === Custom Properties ===
    # These work just like custom properties in ID data blocks
    # Extensive information can be found under
    # http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties
    myStringProperty = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    myFloatProperty = bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=3.1415926)

    # === Optional Functions ===
    # Initialization function, called when a new node is created.
    # This is the most common place to create the sockets for a node, as shown below.
    # NOTE: this is not the same as the standard __init__ function in Python, which is
    #       a purely internal Python method and unknown to the node system!
    def init(self, context):
        self.inputs.new('ArchitectSocketType', "Hello")
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketFloat', "World")
        self.inputs.new('NodeSocketVector', "!")

        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor', "How")
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor', "are")
        self.outputs.new('NodeSocketFloat', "you")

    # Copy function to initialize a copied node from an existing one.
    def copy(self, node):
        print("Copying from node ", node)

    # Free function to clean up on removal.
    def free(self):
        print("Removing node ", self, ", Goodbye!")

    # Additional buttons displayed on the node.
    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        layout.label("Node settings")
        layout.prop(self, "myFloatProperty")

    # Detail buttons in the sidebar.
    # If this function is not defined, the draw_buttons function is used instead
    def draw_buttons_ext(self, context, layout):
        layout.prop(self, "myFloatProperty")
        # myStringProperty button will only be visible in the sidebar
        layout.prop(self, "myStringProperty")

    # Optional: custom label
    # Explicit user label overrides this, but here we can define a label dynamically
    def draw_label(self):
        return "I am a custom node"


class ArchitectNodeCategory(NodeCategory):
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.space_data.tree_type == 'ArchitectNodeTree')


# menu entry for node group tools
def group_tools_draw(self, layout, context):
    layout.operator("node.group_make")
    layout.operator("node.group_ungroup")
    layout.separator()

# maps node tree type to group node type
node_tree_group_type = {
    'CompositorNodeTree': 'CompositorNodeGroup',
    'ShaderNodeTree': 'ShaderNodeGroup',
    'TextureNodeTree': 'TextureNodeGroup',
    'ArchitectNodeTree': 'ArchitectNodeGroup',
    }


# generic node group items generator for shader, compositor and texture node groups
def node_group_items(context):
    if context is None:
        return
    space = context.space_data
    if not space:
        return
    ntree = space.edit_tree
    if not ntree:
        return

    yield NodeItemCustom(draw=group_tools_draw)

    def contains_group(nodetree, group):
        if nodetree == group:
            return True
        else:
            for node in nodetree.nodes:
                if node.bl_idname in node_tree_group_type.values() and node.node_tree is not None:
                    if contains_group(node.node_tree, group):
                        return True
        return False

    for group in context.blend_data.node_groups:
        if group.bl_idname != ntree.bl_idname:
            continue
        # filter out recursive groups
        if contains_group(group, ntree):
            continue

        yield NodeItem(node_tree_group_type[group.bl_idname],
                       group.name,
                       {"node_tree": "bpy.data.node_groups[%r]" % group.name})


# only show input/output nodes inside node groups
def group_input_output_item_poll(context):
    return False


architect_node_categories = [
        ArchitectNodeCategory("ARCH_DEMO", "Demo", items=[
            NodeItem("DemoNodeType"),
            ]),
        ArchitectNodeCategory("ARCH_INPUT", "Input", items=[
            NodeItem("TextureNodeCurveTime"),
            NodeItem("TextureNodeCoordinates"),
            NodeItem("TextureNodeTexture"),
            NodeItem("TextureNodeImage"),
            NodeItem("NodeGroupInput", poll=group_input_output_item_poll),
            ]),
        ArchitectNodeCategory("ARCH_OUTPUT", "Output", items=[
            NodeItem("NodeGroupOutput", poll=group_input_output_item_poll),
            ]),
        ArchitectNodeCategory("ARCH_GROUP", "Group", items=node_group_items),
        ArchitectNodeCategory("ARCH_LAYOUT", "Layout", items=[
            NodeItem("NodeFrame"),
            NodeItem("NodeReroute"),
            ]),
    ]


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ArchitectNodeTree)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ArchitectNodeGroup)
    bpy.utils.register_class(DemoNode)
    nodeitems_utils.register_node_categories('ARCHITECT', architect_node_categories)
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    pass


def unregister():
    nodeitems_utils.unregister_node_categories('ARCHITECT')
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ArchitectNodeGroup)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ArchitectNodeTree)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DemoNode)
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating and editing node groups in a custom node tree needs to be implemented by the code that defines the custom node tree.

See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/58614/935) for an example of implementing custom node groups.